# iOS 11: `UIBarButtonItem`s having placement and usage issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

We have an app that has been around since before the days of storyboards. Prior to iOS 11 everything was fine after we updated it to be 64 bit. We have found two issues when running under iOS 11:

1. On iPhones the single `UIBarButtonItem` in the navigation bar's `RightBarButtonItems` isn't being placed all the way to the right as usual (the left side buttons is in the proper position).
2. On iPads we have what looks much like a segmented control (but made of individual buttons). It works fine when it is not in any kind of bar, but when it is in a bar it doesn't get touches.

In both cases I have used the UI navigator in Xcode to see that iOS 11 has added a couple extra views between bars and buttons. One of the added views is a bar content view (specific class depends on wether it is a toolbar or navigation bar; `_UIToolbarContentView` or `_UINavigationBarContentView`). The other added view is consistent among all kinds of bars, `_UIButtonBarStackView`.

In issue 1 above the added stack view is adding a very wide zero height view after the right bar button that is pushing the button way to the left (like it is trying to fit on an iPhone 4's screen far). Since the class has an underscore in front of it and isn't listed in the docs it must be a private class so even if I did dig into it and figure out how to keep the extra padding from getting added to the end it would get rejected by Apple for using private API.

I can't be sure what of the new views is intercepting the touches for the second issue but given that they are the only real differences I see between iOS 10 & 11 they seem the most likely culprits.

As I mentioned this was built before storyboards so the UI is built in xib files.

Has anyone run into issues with these new views and found a way to solve them? Or should I just rip out the whole UI and rebuild it?

Comment: Doing the same setup in storyboards works just fine so it seems the answer is to not use xib files anymore…